# some characters not display properly using the font GFSArtemisia.otf

Tags: gfsartemisia

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\newfontfamily\grkfont[Script=Greek]{GFSArtemisia.otf}%GFSArtemisia
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}{#1}}}% GREEK TEXT

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
\grk{τῶν ϙ ι ϡ ρ
}
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Characters `ϙ` and `ϡ` are not displayed correctly and displayed as rectangle box, kindly suggest what went wrong in this. Please suggest.

I'm using `XeLaTeX` in `Win10`

Comment: You are loading some packages more than once, you are using Babel and polyglossia at the same time and furthermore your code includes characters that I see as rectangles so perhaps it is not UTF8 / unicode ? Please clean your code and provide a MWE with only the needed packages. Furthermore, explain what character are you trying to obtain.

Comment: @Mane32 Modified as you suggested

Comment: do not load xunicode, do not load xltxtra and decide if you want to use babel or polyglossia, do not use both. Apart from this: the font doesn't have the glyphs so you need another font. E.g. with Times New Roman it works.

Comment: No font has all of Unicode, so you will _always_ get missing characters for some characters you just have to choose a font that has the characters that you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Loading both `babel` and `polyglossia` is wrong, because they fight each other trying to do the same things.
2. `xunicode` and `xltxtra` used to be recommended several years ago, when the LaTeX kernel hadn't be updated to take care of the novelties about Unicode engines.
3. Changing the default language mid-document is not something I'd do.
4. `\setdefaultlanguage` and `\setmainlanguage` are exactly the same (and the latter should be used).
5. Why doing `\grk` inside `greek`?
6. There is no `modern` variant for Greek in `polyglossia`.

Here's a polished version of your document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Greek]
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{GFSArtemisia.otf}[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Greek]

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=monotonic]{greek}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}% GREEK TEXT

\begin{document}

\grk{τῶν ϙ ι ϡ ρ}

\end{document}
```

But we still get

```
Missing character: There is no ϙ (U+03D9) in font [GFSArtemisia.otf]/OT:script=grek;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ϡ (U+03E1) in font [GFSArtemisia.otf]/OT:script=grek;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

which means that GFS Artemisia doesn't contain glyphs for the koppa and sampi characters.

You can import them from another font and it seems that DejaVu Serif blends well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Script=Greek,
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
]
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{GFSArtemisia.otf}[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Script=Greek,
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
]
\newfontfamily{\supplementalfont}{DejaVu Serif}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase]

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=monotonic]{greek}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}% GREEK TEXT

%%% supplement for koppa and sampi
\newunicodechar{ϙ}{{\supplementalfont ϙ}}
\newunicodechar{ϡ}{{\supplementalfont ϡ}}


\begin{document}

\grk{τῶν ϙ ι ϡ ρ}

\end{document}
```

[image]