How to render special unicode chars?
I have converted a large web document into a LaTeX. The document builds successfully, but there are numerous Unicode characters that are not supported by the LaTeX fonts.
I build by document with:
latexmk -xelatex 

I tried to install Libertinus then run:
fc-cache -f -v
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=libertinus.map

but I get some issues:
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Libertinus Serif" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "Math".


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'Libertinus Serif' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.


Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (ssty) not
(fontspec)                available for font 'Libertinus Serif' with script
(fontspec)                'CustomDefault' and language 'Default'.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   U
l.14 \setmathfont
                 [range={U+1F300-U+1F5FF}]{Libertinus Serif}

It seems however that the fonts are installed:
$ fc-list :family | grep Libertinus
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf: Libertinus Serif:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSans-Regular.otf: Libertinus Sans:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusMath-Regular.otf: Libertinus Math:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-BoldItalic.otf: Libertinus Serif:style=Bold Italic
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-Italic.otf: Libertinus Serif:style=Italic
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerifInitials-Regular.otf: Libertinus Serif Initials:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerifDisplay-Regular.otf: Libertinus Serif Display:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSans-Italic.otf: Libertinus Sans:style=Italic
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-SemiboldItalic.otf: Libertinus Serif,Libertinus Serif Semibold Italic:style=Semibold Italic,Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-Bold.otf: Libertinus Serif:style=Bold
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSans-Bold.otf: Libertinus Sans:style=Bold
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusSerif-Semibold.otf: Libertinus Serif,Libertinus Serif Semibold:style=Semibold,Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusMono-Regular.otf: Libertinus Mono:style=Regular
/home/ycr/.local/share/fonts/LibertinusKeyboard-Regular.otf: Libertinus Keyboard:style=Regular

Is there a way to include all the fonts that a browser uses to render these missing characters?
Here is the list of the missing characters:
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{textcomp} % For ©, ™
\usepackage{amsmath} % For ±
\usepackage{amssymb} % For ®
\usepackage{gensymb} % For ±
\usepackage{wasysym} % For fractions
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={U+0251-U+1F9F}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont[range={U+1F300-U+1F5FF}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont[range={U+1F600-U+1F64F}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont[range={U+1F680-U+1F6FF}]{Libertinus Serif}

\setmonofont{FiraMono}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  Scale=0.9,
]

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item 〰 (U+3030)
\item ↧ (U+21A7)
\item ∧ (U+2227)
\item ⊕ (U+2295)
\item ◿ (U+25FF)
\item ❤ (U+2764)
\item ⨼ (U+2A3C)
\item ♯ (U+266F)
\item  (U+1D13D)
\item  (U+1F4A9)
\item  (U+1F614)
\item  (U+1F814)
\item ➀ (U+2780)
\item ⅓ (U+2153)
\item ➁ (U+2781)
\item ⅔ (U+2154)
\item ➂ (U+2782)
\item ɑ (U+0251)
\item ɡ (U+0261)
\item ɔ (U+0254)
\item ʁ (U+0281)
\item ά (U+03AC)
\item α (U+03B1)
\item ὰ (U+1F70)
\item ᾶ (U+1FB6)
\item γ (U+03B3)
\item δ (U+03B4)
\item ε (U+03B5)
\item Ἐ (U+1F18)
\item η (U+03B7)
\item ῆ (U+1FC6)
\item ι (U+03B9)
\item ὶ (U+1F76)
\item κ (U+03BA)
\item λ (U+03BB)
\item μ (U+03BC)
\item ν (U+03BD)
\item ο (U+03BF)
\item ό (U+03CC)
\item π (U+03C0)
\item ρ (U+03C1)
\item ς (U+03C2)
\item σ (U+03C3)
\item τ (U+03C4)
\item ω (U+03C9)
\item ῶ (U+1FF6)
\item ا (U+0627)
\item ب (U+0628)
\item پ (U+067E)
\item ت (U+062A)
\item ر (U+0631)
\item س (U+0633)
\item ع (U+0639)
\item ن (U+0646)
\item ह (U+0939)
\item இ (U+0B87)
\item ச (U+0B9A)
\item ம (U+0BAE)
\item ர (U+0BB0)
\item வ (U+0BB5)
\item ன (U+0BA9)
\item ஜ (U+0B9C)
\item ா (U+0BBE)
\item ி (U+0BBF)
\item ீ (U+0BC0)
\item ு (U+0BC1)
\item ் (U+0BCD)
\item ㄱ (U+3131)
\item 국 (U+AD6D)
\item ㄴ (U+3134)
\item ㄷ (U+3137)
\item ㄹ (U+3139)
\item ㅁ (U+3141)
\item ㅂ (U+3142)
\item ㅅ (U+3145)
\item ㅇ (U+3147)
\item 어 (U+C5B4)
\item ㅈ (U+3148)
\item ㅊ (U+314A)
\item ㅋ (U+314B)
\item ㅌ (U+314C)
\item ㅍ (U+314D)
\item ㅎ (U+314E)
\item 한 (U+D55C)
\item ㅏ (U+314F)
\item ㅑ (U+3151)
\item ㅓ (U+3153)
\item ㅕ (U+3155)
\item ㅗ (U+3157)
\item ㅛ (U+315B)
\item ㅜ (U+315C)
\item ㅠ (U+3160)
\item ㅡ (U+3161)
\item ㅣ (U+3163)
\item あ (U+3042)
\item い (U+3044)
\item う (U+3046)
\item え (U+3048)
\item お (U+304A)
\item か (U+304B)
\item き (U+304D)
\item く (U+304F)
\item け (U+3051)
\item こ (U+3053)
\item さ (U+3055)
\item し (U+3057)
\item す (U+3059)
\item せ (U+305B)
\item そ (U+305D)
\item た (U+305F)
\item ち (U+3061)
\item つ (U+3064)
\item て (U+3066)
\item と (U+3068)
\item な (U+306A)
\item に (U+306B)
\item ぬ (U+306C)
\item ね (U+306D)
\item の (U+306E)
\item は (U+306F)
\item ひ (U+3072)
\item ふ (U+3075)
\item へ (U+3078)
\item ほ (U+307B)
\item ま (U+307E)
\item み (U+307F)
\item む (U+3080)
\item め (U+3081)
\item も (U+3082)
\item や (U+3084)
\item ゆ (U+3086)
\item よ (U+3088)
\item ら (U+3089)
\item り (U+308A)
\item る (U+308B)
\item れ (U+308C)
\item ろ (U+308D)
\item わ (U+308F)
\item を (U+3092)
\item ん (U+3093)
\item 九 (U+4E5D)
\item 八 (U+516B)
\item 十 (U+5341)
\item 千 (U+5343)
\item 官 (U+5B98)
\item 尋 (U+5C0B)
\item 日 (U+65E5)
\item 本 (U+672C)
\item 爺 (U+723A)
\item 神 (U+795E)
\item 話 (U+8A71)
\item 語 (U+8A9E)
\item 话 (U+8BDD)
\item 釜 (U+91DC)
\item 隠 (U+96A0)
\item 零 (U+96F6)
\item � (U+FFFD)

\end{itemize}

\end{document}


The errors suggest that the font doesn't have a math table: have you seen information that it does?

In general, all fonts doesn't have all characters, you can fetch those missing unicode characters from other fonts

@MadyYuvi At least if I can find a way to add fallback fonts for searching the missing chars. It seems unicode-math isn't the solution :(

This link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708191/some-characters-not-display-properly-using-the-font-gfsartemisia-otf will helps you

@MadyYuvi It would involve to identify each single char, find the font in which it fits, then wrap those chars with \fontxy{...} I tried also to use \newfontfamily{\fallbackfont}, but I don't get any result yet.

your document is not using math at all but the error is the U+ syntax which should not be used for the range parameter, but even if you fixed that so fixed the error you show it would have no effect on the characters used in text mode in the body of the document

You can build you project with LuaLaTeX and use the following to add fallback for all missing chars:
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("fontfallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;",
      "Symbola:mode=harf;",
      "NotoNaskhArabic:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifHebrew:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifDevanagari:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTamil:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTibetan:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  RawFeature={fallback=fontfallback}
]


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french,english,greek,bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{kotex}

\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("fontfallback",
    {
      "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf;",
      "Symbola:mode=harf;",
      "NotoNaskhArabic:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifHebrew:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifDevanagari:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTamil:mode=harf;",
      "NotoSerifTibetan:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  RawFeature={fallback=fontfallback}
]

\begin{document}

\section{Foobar}

\subsection{Symbols}

〰, ∧, ⊕, ♯, ⨼, , 

➀, ➁, ➂, ④, ⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧, ⑨, ⑩, ⑪, ⑫, ⑬, ⑭, ⑮, ⑯, ⑰, ⑱, ⑲, ⑳

\subsection{Emoji}

, ❤️, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ✨, , , , , 

\subsection{Korean}
ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ
ㄲ, ㄸ, ㅃ, ㅆ, ㅉ
ㅏ, ㅑ, ㅓ, ㅕ, ㅗ, ㅛ, ㅜ, ㅠ, ㅡ, ㅣ, ㅐ, ㅒ, ㅔ, ㅖ, ㅘ, ㅙ, ㅚ, ㅝ, ㅞ, ㅟ, ㅢ
갯, 냉, 댁, 랭, 맹, 백, 색, 앵, 쟉, 책, 캭, 탱, 팽, 행
개, 내, 대, 래, 매, 배, 새, 애, 재, 채, 캐, 태, 패, 해
갂, 갇, 갅, 갆, 갇, 갏, 갉, 갊, 갋, 갌, 갍, 갎, 갏, 값

\subsection{Japanese}
あ, い, う, え, お, か, き, く, け, こ, さ, し, す, せ, そ, た, ち, つ, て, と, な, に, ぬ, ね, の, は, ひ, ふ, へ, ほ, ま, み, む, め, も, や, ゆ, よ, ら, り, る, れ, ろ, わ, を, ん

ア, イ, ウ, エ, オ, カ, キ, ク, ケ, コ, サ, シ, ス, セ, ソ, タ, チ, ツ, テ, ト, ナ, ニ, ヌ, ネ, ノ, ハ, ヒ, フ, ヘ, ホ, マ, ミ, ム, メ, モ, ヤ, ユ, ヨ, ラ, リ, ル, レ, ロ, ワ, ヲ, ン

日, 一, 国, 人, 年, 大, 十, 二, 本, 中, 長, 出, 三, 時, 行, 見, 月, 五, 後, 前, 生, 間, 上, 東, 四, 今, 金, 九, 入, 学, 高, 円, 子, 外, 八, 六, 下, 来, 気, 小, 七, 山, 話, 女, 北, 午, 書, 半, 西, 電, 語, 土, 父, 母, 間, 友, 開, 天

\subsection{Greek}

Α, Β, Γ, Δ, Ε, Ζ, Η, Θ, Ι, Κ, Λ, Μ, Ν, Ξ, Ο, Π, Ρ, Σ, Τ, Υ, Φ, Χ, Ψ, Ω
α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ, η, θ, ι, κ, λ, μ, ν, ξ, ο, π, ρ, σ, τ, υ, φ, χ, ψ, ω

\subsection{Arabic}
ا, ب, ت, ث, ج, ح, خ, د, ذ, ر, ز, س, ش, ص, ض, ط, ظ, ع, غ, ف, ق, ك, ل, م, ن, ه, و, ي

\subsection{Hebrew}

א, ב, ג, ד, ה, ו, ז, ח, ט, י, כ, ל, מ, נ, ס, ע, פ, צ, ק, ר, ש, ת

\subsection{Russian}

А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е, Ё, Ж, З, И, Й, К, Л, М, Н, О, П, Р, С, Т, У, Ф, Х, Ц, Ч, Ш, Щ, Ъ, Ы, Ь, Э, Ю, Я

a, б, в, г, д, е, ё, ж, з, и, й, к, л, м, н, о, п, р, с, т, у, ф, х, ц, ч, ш, щ, ъ, ы, ь, э, ю, я

\subsection{Tibetan}

ཀ, ཁ, ག, ང, ཅ, ཆ, ཇ, ཉ, ཏ, ཐ, ད, ན, པ, ཕ, བ, མ, ཙ, ཚ, ཛ, ཝ, ཞ, ཟ, འ, ཡ, ར, ལ, ཤ, ས, ཧ, ཨ

ཨ, ཨཱ, ཨི, ཨཱི, ཨུ, ཨཱུ, ཨེ, ཨཻ, ཨོ, ཨཽ, ཨྀ, ཨཱྀ

ྐ

\end{document}

